# logging to file and screen

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to enable logging of a node to both file and screen? And why does setting output="screen" disable logging to file?

I would like to see log messages at runtime on the screen, but still be able to recheck log messages at a later stage without having to copy/paste my terminal screens to a file.

I suppose I could use rqt_console to see the log messages at runtime, but as I understand that would put more strain on my network and I already have timing issues as it is without overloading my network with debug messages.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162786/logging-to-file-and-screen/) by [Dominik](https://answers.ros.org/users/4965/dominik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a bug (or a feature) in how roslaunch is implementing output to screen. I would file it against the ros_comm issue tracker: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dominik](https://answers.ros.org/users/4965/dominik/) on 2014-05-08**:
I'm not sure if we have to distinguish between roslaunch log and a node's log. Roslaunch seems to log always to a file, but only startup/shutdown messages. The node itself however doesn't log to a file when output="screen". But I will follow your advice and create an issue and see about the response

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-07-24**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/409 is tracking this issue, it is still open in need of a PR.